# PHP code not changing database table values

Tags: php

What is wrong in this piece of code?

```
<?php
require_once 'dbcon.php';


if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
 $email = $_GET['email'];
 $code = $_GET['code'];

 $statusY = "Y";
 $statusN = "N";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email,code,id,verified FROM users WHERE email=:uID AND code=:code LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$email,":code"=>$code));
 $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
 {
  if($row['verified'] == 0)
  {
     
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET verified=1 WHERE email=:uID");

   $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$email);
   $stmt->execute();

   $msg = "
             <div class='alert alert-success'>

       <strong>WoW !</strong>  Tu cuenta ha sido activada :
          </div>
          ";
        
  }
  else
  {
   $msg = "
             <div class='alert alert-error'>

       <strong>sorry !</strong>  Tu cuenta ya estaba activada :
          </div>
          ";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $msg = "
         <div class='alert alert-error'>
      <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
      <strong>sorry !</strong>  Tu cuenta de usuario no existe.
      </div>
      ";
 }
}

?>
```

I am not getting any error.log update and it is not working, the database table is not changing its values as requested.

Here you have dbcon.php:

```
<?php
class Database
{
     
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "f....";
    private $username = "f....";
    private $password = "g9hr#.....";
    public $conn;
     
    public function dbConnection()
 {
     
     $this->conn = null;    
        try
  {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
   $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        }
  catch(PDOException $exception)
  {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
         
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What message do you get when you execute the code and it is "not working"?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than "its not working". What is it suppose to do? What does it do instead?  Does it display any errors on the page? (turn on display_errors)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, here you have the URL that is launching the php file: https://faro.red/evanzero/verify.php?email=modes@faro.red&code=6e7a4870b61dbf5a9c9f71721955c317  and the servers no error, only  the default screen for not founded pages

Comment: @Phaelaxz, same response as my comment to KIKO Software

Comment: @mvasco that's going to happen when we're both writing a response at the same time.

Comment: You're not writing to the error log anywhere. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php for more info about how to use it. It can be as simple as adding `error_log("my test message");` to start to try to debug your code.

Comment: It might not like the `@` in your email argument. I tried this: https://faro.red/evanzero/verify.php?email=modes%40faro.red&code=6e7a4870b61dbf5a9c9f71721955c317 and got an blank page.

Comment: I have access now to the error log, this is the output: HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /../evanzero/verify.php:18

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I have access now to the error log, this is the output: HP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /../evanzero/verify.php:18

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones, I have access now to the error log, this is the output: HP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /../evanzero/verify.php:18

Comment: Yes, you still need to create the database connection.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, it is created in dbcon.php, or it isn't?

Comment: No, it is not, you create a database class, but you never instantiate it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, would you tell me how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240186/discussion-between-mvasco-and-kiko-software).

Comment: You never do: `$conn = (new Database())->dbConnection();`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, it is working now